# How to record all audio streams in a single object inside Twilio Video?

Tags: twilio, webrtc, streaming, twilio-api, twilio-video

I use Twilio Video to create a video chat app.

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/get-started-with-twilio-video-python-flask-server). Different people can join a room and talk. How to record all the audio tracks, merge them, and send them to the server?

The following code records audio from only one local participant:

```
const handleSuccess = function (stream) {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
        chunks.push(event.data);
        sendDataFull(chunks)
    });
    mediaRecorder.start(5000);
};
const chunks = [];
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false }).then(handleSuccess);
```

Answer (score 0):

If is not necessary to use that code to record your meetings.

If plan to record your meetings always, you could configure this in the console (you have to use group rooms): https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/video/manage/room-settings?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fvideo%2Fconfigure%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1

If only some meetings will be recorded, you can use Recording Rules API, with this API it is also possible to select the tracks that will be recorded:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recording-rules

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).